# AoBScan memory.dll c# not getting values

Tags: c#

I'm playing around with memory.dll in visual studio trying to do a AoBscan of a Cemu game (Botw).
I'm using the following code but it dosent get any value. What am i doing wrong? Apreciate your help.

```
public async void SampleAoBScan()
        {
            // open the process and check if it was successful before the AoB scan
            if (!m.OpenProcess("Cemu")) // you can also specify the process ID. Check Wiki for more info.
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Process Is Not Found or Open!", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }
            int pID = m.GetProcIdFromName("Cemu");
            MessageBox.Show("ID do Cemu: "+pID);
            // AoB scan and store it in AoBScanResults. We specify our start and end address regions to decrease scan time.
            IEnumerable<long> AoBScanResults = await m.AoBScan(0x20000000000, 0x30000000000, "?? ff ff ff f1 3f ?? ?? ?? 80 00 ?? ?? 11 ?? ?? ?? 10 df ?? ?? 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3f 80", false, true);

            // get the first found address, store it in the variable SingleAoBScanResult
            long SingleAoBScanResult = AoBScanResults.FirstOrDefault();

            // pop up message box that shows our first result
            MessageBox.Show("Our First Found Address is " + SingleAoBScanResult);

            // Ex: iterate through each found address. This prints each address in the debug console in Visual Studio.
            foreach (long res in AoBScanResults)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("I found the address {0} in the AoB scan."+ res, null);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Clearly it can't find a match in the memory region. What makes you think a match exists?

Comment: i use "?? ff ff ff f1 3f ?? ?? ?? 80 00 ?? ?? 11 ?? ?? ?? 10 df ?? ?? 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3f 80" in cheat engine using "search for this array" and it always finds 1 match.

Comment: Is the `for each` being executed at all? Also: `MessageBox.Show("I found the address {0} in the AoB scan."+ res` This will not insert `res` into the string. You need `$"I found the address {res} in the AoB scan."`

Comment: No i dont think the "for each" is being executed, but probalbly since Aobscanresults is "0".

Comment: Any other way to do an AoBscan in c#?